# Equality check with "in" operator

Tags: python, list

What is happening when I use the following syntax?

```
>>> 1 == 1 in [1]
True
>>> 1 == 2 in [1]
False
```

To make it even more complex:

```
>>> class A:
        def __init__(self):    
                self.i = 0
        def __call__(self):
                self.i += 1
                return self.i
>>> a = A()
>>> a()
1
>>> 2 == 2 in [a(), a()] # Here a() should only be evaluated once
True
>>> a() # But in fact it was evaluated twice
4
>>> 5 == 6 in [a(), a()] # Here a() should be evaluated twice because in need to compare with each elements in the list
False
>>> a() # But in fact it was not evaluated at all
5
```

I read that `in` operator is calling the `__contains__` method of a list, but

```
>>> [1].__contains__(1 == 1) # 1 is equal to True
True
>>> [2].__contains__(2 == 2)
False
```

To my best knowledge, this question was not asked before. It is really really confusing for me now so any information would be much appreciated!

Comment: In the last case ```[2].__contains__(2 == 2)``` where  ```2 == 2``` is return True so which is not equal to [2].

Comment: The duplicate isn't explicit, but both `==` and `in` are considered comparison operators, hence the applicability. `a == b in c` is equivalent to `a == b and b in c`, not `(a == b) in c`.

Comment: @chepner Oh My God! Thank you so much!

Comment: Interestingly enough you'd get the same results, but for a different reason,  if you used parentheses to force the first comparison to be evaluated. e.g. `(1 == 1) in [1]` is `True` because `1 == 1` is `True` and `True` is in `[1]` (that is, `True == 1`).

Comment: Regarding your last examples, `[a(), a()]` always calls `a` twice, if it gets evaluated at all. In the `2 == 2` test that's exactly what happens, since the first comparison is true. The second time out, `5 == 6` is false, so the implicit `and` in the chained comparison short circuits and the list is never created. What you might find even more interesting is that `1 == a() == 2` will only ever call `a()` once, despite otherwise being like `1 == a() and a() == 2` (which could call it twice). The interpreter caches the value returned from the single call and uses it for both comparisons.

Comment: booleans are just numbers in Python, so `1 == 1` will evaluate to `True` (= `1`).